# How to get all supported opentype settings for a font?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, font-design, font-management, opentype

I’m using often open source fonts from the web for my web projects. One thing I’d like to do, is activating opentype settings like **ligatures** or **kerning** (and in some cases, it would be helpful to check also, if there are any discrete ligatures or stylistic alternates available).

Unfortunately, most fonts aren’t very well documented when it comes to opentype settings, so I’m searching for a software or tool which gives me a quick overview over all supported opentype settings.

How do you get an overview over all supported opentype settings for a specific font?

Thanks for your ideas and comments!

Comment: Hi Tibor, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Most font managers should tell you this.

I'm not sure what you use, but I can show you in FontExplorer X Pro.

Open the font 'information' window (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on OS X), then under 'Detailed Preview', all available OpenType features are shown in the right column, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi,

that’s what I’m looking for. Do you have an idea if such a function is available in Suitcase 6 as well?

Comment: I can't find anything similar in Suitcase Fusion 6. You can use the 'Glyph View' to see ligatures etc but that's about it as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

The title and the content of your post seem to be asking different questions:

1. For an overview of the features in a given font, that information is almost always listed on the website you got the font from.  There are also many free and paid apps for graphics, type-design, character maps, and font management (such as FontExplorer) that can show you this info.
2. Now, regarding which of these features and character sets are available online as webfonts, it will not be the same for every font, and is likely to depend on factors such as browser support, and the service being used to host the font files...but a simple web search for "opentype features on the web" revealed plenty of sites you should take a look at.  Here are a few that caught my eye:

https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/open-type-syntax.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/use-open-type-features.html

http://blog.webtype.com/?p=4085

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings

http://clagnut.com/sandbox/css3/

https://www.typotheque.com/articles/opentype_features_in_web_browsers_-_tests